# save() method only writing last record in foreach loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

```
 foreach ($updateOrInsert as $subordinate) {

        if ($key = array_search($subordinate, $existingDowns))
        {
         // $update[] = ['id'=>$key,'up'=>$up,'down'=>$subordinate,'status'=>0];
          $hierarchy = Hierarchy::find($key);

          $hierarchy->status = 0;

          $hierarchy->save();
      }
      else{
          $insert[] = ['up'=>$up,'down'=>$subordinate];
      }
  }
```

Here $key is the id of `hierarchies` table. the above code only update the last id only. I googled for this problem and spend couple of hours but no luck. Any idea?

Comment: Try `$hierarchy->update();`. About the `array_search()` it's impossible to tell what really happens there. But if you believe more than the last `$updateOrInsert` is true, then more rows should get updated. Why not `updateOrInsert`? Because $hierarchy has to exist in the database. If not, $hierarchy is NULL, saving only the status as a new record will probably fail because of lack of required data.

Comment: Try to change this line to ```if ($key = array_search($subordinate, $existingDowns) !== false)```, the function can return a 0 (zero) what would result in a "false" in your if